# Python - regex from bye like-object

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I use the following code in windows:

```
hostname = Popen(['hostname'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

print(stdout)

regex = compile(b'('CO.*)')

m = regex.match(stdout)
if m != None:
    print(m)
else:
    print("Doesn't match")
```

I get the output:

```
b'COMPUTER\r\n'
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match=b'COMPUTER\r'>
```

I know, i can use much simpler in this case (but for some reason i don't want to use it):

```
socket.gethostname()
```

The problem is, i don't like whole output from regex match:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match=b'COMPUTER\r'>
```

I wan't only `COMPUTER`.

Is that possible, without using another regex?

Comment: have you tried `m.group(1).decode("ascii")` ?

Comment: That's briliant!. Please post it as an. answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print `m` you get the *representation* of the `sre` object (for debug purposes)

To overcome the minor hiccups to get to your string you can do:

```
m.group(1).decode("ascii").rstrip()
```

- extracting the group from regex
- decoding to a `str` (remove the `b` prefix)
- and strip off the CR+LF trailing chars from `subprocess` output

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the byte string: `m.group(1)`. But for this problem, do not use regex, it’s overkill. Instead, use `if stdout.startswith(b'CO'):`

Your regex contains a Python syntax error, you do not need to compile a regex (`re.match(b'(CO.*)', stdout)` will do it). Why not use `socket.gethostbyname()`? Are you doing something other than `hostname` in the real code?

Comment: Yes, `hostname` it's only for this example, i will have to use regex, becouse, i will seek for few variables for numbers of commands, not system only. But i like `.startswith().